# Compare value and add if matches to an array

Tags: javascript

Im trying to merge 2 data sources in 1, I wanna loop through them and if a specefic value matches than add it to the first object with the same value and add the in the emty array what is already there. No matter how much objects I have.

So lets say I have this information

Source 1

```
one = {
    "teams": [
        {
            name: 'ABC',
            members: [],
            rooms: '0'
        },
        {
            name: 'DEF',
            members: [],
            rooms: '1'
        }
    ]
}
```

Source 2

```
two = {
    "persons": [
        {
            name: 'Foo',
            gender: 'male',
            room: '1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Bar',
            gender: 'female',
            room: '2'
        }
    ]
}
```

And what I want is that the 'persons' array merge to the members array if the 'room and rooms' value matches.

What I would assume is something similar like this:

```
 for(var i = 0 ; i < two.persons.length; i++) {
    if (one.teams[i].rooms == two.persons[i].room) {
            data.teams[i].members.push(two.persons[i]);
        }
 }
```

Comment: you need at least two independent loops

Comment: Where needs the other loop, inside the one that already excist?

Comment: @DennisWegereef Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zf15qdvL/) (look at the console output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using higher order methods you can do:

```js
one = {
    "teams": [
        {
            name: 'ABC',
            members: [],
            rooms: '0'
        },
        {
            name: 'DEF',
            members: [],
            rooms: '1'
        }
    ]
};

two = {
    "persons": [
        {
            name: 'Foo',
            gender: 'male',
            room: '1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Bar',
            gender: 'female',
            room: '2'
        }
    ]
};

var ttt = one.teams.map(function(x){
var roomVal= x.rooms;
    
   x.members = two.persons.filter(function(t){
      return t.room == roomVal});
   return x;
})

one.teams = ttt;
console.log(one)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that once you iterate the `two` array, then you do not go back and see if the previous element matched with the current one.

For example, if `[0]` on each arrays does not match and you iterate to index `[1]` in the for-loop, you do not have a way to check if `two[1]` matched `one[0]`.

To do a complete search, you could directly iterate the arrays for each value of `two`:

```
two.persons.forEach(function(person) {
    one.teams.forEach(function(team) {
        if (team.rooms == person.room) {
            team.members.push(person);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many strategies to do this. But most important you should iterate each array separately. I would use an Array.forEach();

```
one.teams.forEach(function (team, teamsIndex, teamsArray) {
  two.persons.forEach(function (person, personsIndex, personsArray) {
    if (team.room == person.room) {
       // Do what you need to do.
    }
  });
});
```

Didn't check syntax so be aware to read Array.forEach(); documentation.